# Searching managed navigation termset

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there a way to search/find a specific managed navigation term by guid using server object model

This code

```
var termGuid = new Guid(fieldValue.TermGuid);
        var navTermSet = TaxonomyNavigation.GetTermSetForWeb(SPContext.Current.Web, StandardNavigationProviderNames.GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider, true);
        if (navTermSet == null) return String.Empty;
        var navTerm = navTermSet.Terms.Where(c => c.Id == termGuid).FirstOrDefault();

        if (navTerm == null) return String.Empty;
        return navTerm.GetWebRelativeFriendlyUrl();
```

only works if the term is in the first level, if its deeper down in hierarchy it doesn't find it and I'm not seeing any other mechanism that gets me a flat list of terms

It looks like a severe limitation with API

Answer (score 0):

When you're *looking* for a certain term and you don't know how deep this resides and wether it's a parent or child, this becomes more complicated. If the API has no direct way of getting *all* the terms, regardless wether they're child or parent, I guess your best option is to list them all yourself by looping all terms + children and then find them by Guid.

Below code can be used to list all terms. The code is taken and shortened for your ease from [**this article**](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-introduction-to-programmatically-working-with-taxonomies-in-sharepoint-server-2010).

```
List<Term> allTerms = new List<Term>();

void BuildTermList()
{
    SPSite thisSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
    TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession (thisSite);

    foreach (TermStore termStore in session.TermStores)
    {
        foreach (Group group in termStore.Groups)
        {
            foreach (TermSet termSet in group.TermSets)
            {
                foreach (Term term in termSet.Terms)
                {
                    AddTermSet(term);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void AddTermSet(Term term)
{
    allItems.Add(term);

    foreach (Term t in term.Terms)
        AddTermSet(t);
}
```

Now that you have the list you can query it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm talking about Querying Managed Navigation, and yes I'm well aware I could loop through, problem here is Terms property only gives you immediate terms and GetAllTerms is only available from CSOM